# Do not use built-in or reserved HTML elements with Vue, TailwindUI and Headless UI

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-ui, headless-ui

I'm trying to add the TailwindUI / Headless UI Menu (dropdown) to Vue and am getting two errors in the console:

> Do not use built-in or reserved HTML elements as component id: menu

and

> Error: < MenuButton /> is missing a parent < Menu /> component

I'm Using Vue 3 within a Laravel 8 app, here's what app.js looks like:

```
import { Menu, MenuButton, MenuItems, MenuItem } from "@headlessui/vue";
const app = createApp({
  ...
});
app.component('menu', Menu);
app.component('menubutton', MenuButton);
app.component('menuitems', MenuItems);
app.component('menuitem', MenuItem);
app.mount("#app");
```

And here's a minimal example for the view:

```
<Menu>
  <MenuButton>More</MenuButton>
  <MenuItems>
    <MenuItem v-slot="{ active }">
      <a :class='{ "bg-blue-500": active }' href="/test">
        Test
      </a>
    </MenuItem>
  </MenuItems>
</Menu>
```

I've tried everything that I can think of and am lost! Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `<Menu>`-element as it is a [built-in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/menu) HTML element.

Just rename to something like CustomMenu

```html
import { Menu as CustomMenu, ... } from ...
app.component('menu', CustomMenu);
<CustomMenu>
...
```

Comment: Thanks @tauzN, I tried that now but I'm then still getting the error

"Error: <MenuButton /> is missing a parent <Menu /> component."

It looks like in Headless UI the MenuButton needs a parent tag <Menu>. Any ideas?

Comment: actually it does work! I needed to rename all of the imports like this "import { Menu as HeadlessMenu, MenuButton as HeadlessMenuButton, MenuItems as HeadlessMenuItems, MenuItem as HeadlessMenuItem } from "@headlessui/vue";" and then all of the exports like this "app.component('headlessmenu', HeadlessMenu); ... etc", then it's working perfectly. Thank you tauzN!

Comment: Glad to hear. It should not be necessary. It might have been my spelling error, that made it not work. I changed `<CutomMenu>` to `<CustomMenu>`

Comment: I did try try that, only importing the menu "as" and leaving the rest as they were but I'm then getting a "Failed to resolve component" error for menubutton, menuitem and menuitems. When I renamed all of them so that each one had the same prefix it worked. In any case it's working perfectly now, thanks again!